# Custom Simulink Discrete-time integrator block for Bogacki Shampine

Tags: integration, simulink, integrator

I am trying to create my own discrete time integrator in Simulink Using the Bogacki Shampine rule. The general formula for the rule (when it is only a function of time) is:

```
y(n+1) = y(n) + (t/9)*(2*s1+3*s2+4s3)
```

where:

```
s1 = x(n)
s2 = x(n+h/2)
s3 = x(n+3h/4)
```

which is also equal to :

```
y(n) = y(n-1) + (t/9)*(2*s1+3*s2+4s3) ;
```

where:

```
s1 = x(n-1)
s2 = x(n-h/2)
s3 = x(n-h/4)
```

[image]

Then I compared the results with the simple integrator block that uses ode3 (Bogacki Shampine). Results were close to each other but not too much. 
Also I am not sure that I create this integrator in a correct way. Since Bogacki Shampine is 3rd order. I thought I should have used 3 unit delay, but 2 was enough for me.

How can I improve this or create another one to get more accurate results?

Comment: Your implementation seems dubious. For instance, you are assuming that x(n-1/2) = (x(n)+x(n-1))/2, which is almost certainly not the case.  It would mean that the mid-point is just an average of the end points, which would be the same as the Trapizoidal Rule.

Comment: Yes sir you are right. But i did it the way you said since matlab does not allow me to put different sampling times in one model. Do you have any suggestions to deal with this problem?  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: In Simulink each block can have a sample time independent of the overall model sample time.  At a minimum you need to have 2 additional states, one of them with a rate to give you x(n-1/2) and one to give you x(n-1/4).  You would then combine those with you states giving x(n-1) and y(k-1) to get the result.